ADB server does not start when VPN is active
On my MacBook (Sonoma 14.6.1) I have adb installed (using homebrew - version 35.0.2-12147458). It works well until I activate VPN.
My company uses Cisco AnyConnect.
Once VPN is enabled, I am getting this:
> adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/96/g55p8hzj7wx9pl5y2qypzjcw0000gp/T//adb.502.log
Server had pid: 80435
--- adb starting (pid 80435) ---
09-10 10:47:12.397 80435 47875737 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
09-10 10:47:12.397 80435 47875737 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Version 35.0.2-12147458
09-10 10:47:12.397 80435 47875737 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Installed as /opt/homebrew/bin/adb
09-10 10:47:12.397 80435 47875737 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Running on Darwin 23.6.0 (arm64)
09-10 10:47:12.397 80435 47875737 I adb     : main.cpp:63 
09-10 10:47:12.406 80435 47875737 I adb     : auth.cpp:416 adb_auth_init...
09-10 10:47:12.407 80435 47875737 I adb     : auth.cpp:152 loaded new key from '/Users/anton.avtamonov/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint 2D331848B6E6BE21327954C681930EEF0EFD536A0B8A9C5197F7567428D36020
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:170 AdbUdpSocket fd=10
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:170 AdbUdpSocket fd=8
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:274 SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=14
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:533 bind endpoint=0.0.0.0:5353
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:274 SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=14
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:558 bind endpoint=[0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353 scope_id=0
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:170 AdbUdpSocket fd=12
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:274 SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=15
09-10 10:47:12.408 80435 47875737 I adb     : udp_socket.cpp:558 bind endpoint=[0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353 scope_id=0
09-10 10:47:12.473 80435 47875737 F adb     : udp_socket.cpp:447 Check failed: static_cast<size_t>(num_bytes_sent) == length (static_cast<size_t>(num_bytes_sent)=12, length=33) 

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon

I suspect that it is because the VPN impede udp traffic in some way, but I am not sure. It can also be that VPN uses 0.0.0.0 as the default route that somehow affects adb's ability to send a test datagram.
I tried to first start the adb server and then connect to VPN. That seems to work or at least I can do 'adb connect' after re-enabling VPN and it does not fail.
I do not know how adb uses udp and multicast and how critical this all is for its operations.
The question is if there is a way to tell adb to bind to only ipv4 and maybe specify the interface to bind. Or whatever else that you can suggest.  Adb is used by millions and Cisco Anyconnect is not that rare either. I cannot believe I am the only one that is facing this issue, but I did not find anything...
This is not specific to my computer - this is not working the same way for everybody in our group.

You mention adb connect what is the target IP you connect to, en emulator or an Android device in your local network? If you open VPN client there should be an info page displaying the routing details. What unprotected routes do you see? Is your local LAN unprotected? If not you won't be able to connect to devices in your LAN while VPN is active. If or if not local networks are accessible is configured by your VPN admins.

Well, I do not think that connecting to the android devices is relevant. I cannot start the server, which preceeds any other operations, like connecting devices, listing them, etc. Right..?
adb start-server fails, and it fails at the initialization step when it tries to send a test datagram which I assume goes between console adb app and the adb server it is starting, but I do not really know. There is no any 'target IPs' involved at this point - this is all a local box operation.

I faced this issue as well in macOS 14.7 using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client version 4.9.04053. I updated Android Studio to Ladybug 2024.2.1 and immediately noticed the issue. Downgrading to Koala Feature Drop 2024.1.2 Patch 1 solved the issue. So it seems there's a behavior change in Ladybug 2024.2.1 that caused this. I can't identify the root cause. Downgrading is the temporary workaround until hopefully it's fixed in future versions of Android Studio. I'm also in the process of getting the latest version of Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client to see if this will fix the issue.

Interesting this is happening with both AnyConnect and WARP!  Maybe it really is an adb issue.

Same issue with Cloudflare WARP October release. After driving me nuts during deadline crunch time, this worked:
ADB_MDNS_OPENSCREEN=0 adb start-server


Thank you very much! This worked for me too

Thanks, This helped me for my VPN connections.

Can't upvote this multiple times but after 4h of trying and chatting with SysAdmin this one fixed it.

You can try this alternative by connecting adb via USB instead of network
Steps
Disconnect VPN and connect the devices and try the following
$ adb devices ---> Your device should be detected
$ adb shell
$ adb shell
> setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1
> stop adbd
> start adbd

Hope it helps, adb will use USB instead of network

The solution for me was to temporarily disabled unused interfaces, such as AirDrop's awdl0 interface:
sudo ifconfig awdl0 down
